# Custom pagination, "next" and "last" button doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination

I am currently creating my custom pagination for my simple project in c# asp.net, so far so good, but the "Next" and "Last" button doesn't work properly. The "Next" button just returns the current page, or if I'm at another page greater than 1, it goes back 1 page.

The "Last" button doesn't go to the last page as expected.

I know it's just something in the `for` loop in the view, or there's something I'm missing in the models file.

Here's my code so far:

**Index.cshtml (View)**

```
@model FinalPaginationTask.Models.UserCustom
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/***.css" />
                <title> </title>
            </head>
        <body>

            <h2>List of Users</h2>
                @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.Hidden("SortField", Model.SortField)
                    @Html.Hidden("SortDirection", Model.SortDirection)
                    @Html.Hidden("PageCount", Model.PageCount)
                    @Html.Hidden("PageSize", Model.PageSize)
                    @Html.Hidden("CurrentPageIndex", Model.CurrentPageIndex)

                    @*@Html.Hidden("SelectedUsr_Id", Model.SelectedUsr_Id)
                        @Html.Hidden("SelectedUsername", Model.SelectedUsername)*@

                    <table id="customers" class="table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th >
                                <a href="#" data-sortfield="usr_Id" class="header">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.user.First().usr_Id)</a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <a href="#" data-sortfield="username" class="header">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.user.First().username)</a>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.user.First().email)
                            </th>
                            <th>

                            </th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            @*<th>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedUsr_Id,
                                        new SelectList(Model.userDDL, "usr_Id", "usr_Id", Model.SelectedUsr_Id), "All", new { @id = "fn" })
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedUsername,
                                    new SelectList(Model.userDDL, "username", "username", Model.SelectedUsername), "All", new { @id = "ln" })
                                </th>*@
                        </tr>

                        @foreach (var item in Model.user)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.usr_Id)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Create User", "CreateUser", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        <tr></tr>

                        @*@if (Model.Pager.LastPage > 1)
                        {*@

                            <tr class="pagination">
                                @if (Model.CurrentPageIndex >= 1)
                                {
                                    <td class="pager"><a href="~/User/">First</a></td>
                                    <td class="pager"><a href="~/User/Index/@(Model.CurrentPageIndex - 1)">Previous</a></td>
                                }
                                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PageCount; i++)
                                {

                                    if (i == Model.CurrentPageIndex)
                                    {
                                        <td class="pager"><span class="current-pager" id="CurrentPageIndex">@(i + 1)</span></td>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            <td class="pager" ><a href="~/User/Index/@i" data-pageindex="@i" class="pager">@(i + 1)</a></td>
                                    }
                                }
                                @if (Model.CurrentPageIndex < Model.PageCount)
                                {
                                    <td class="pager"><a href="~/User/Index/@(Model.CurrentPageIndex + 1)">Next</a></td>
                                    <td class="pager"><a href="~/User/Index/@(Model.PageCount)">Last</a></td>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        @*}*@

                    </table>
                }
        </body>
    </html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".header").click(function (evt) {
                var sortfield = $(evt.target).data("sortfield");
                if ($("#SortField").val() == sortfield) {
                    if ($("#SortDirection").val() == "ascending") {
                        $("#SortDirection").val("descending");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#SortDirection").val("ascending");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("#SortField").val(sortfield);
                    $("#SortDirection").val("ascending");
                }
                evt.preventDefault();
                $("form").submit();

            });

            $(".pager").click(function (evt) {
                var pageindex = $(evt.target).data("pageindex");
                $("#CurrentPageIndex").val(pageindex);
                evt.preventDefault();
                $("form").submit();
            });

            $("#fn").change(function (evt) {
                $("#SelectedUsr_Id").val($("#fn").val().trim());
                evt.preventDefault();
                $("form").submit();
            })
            $("#ln").change(function (evt) {
                $("#SelectedUsername").val($("#ln").val().trim());
                evt.preventDefault();
                $("form").submit();
            })
        });
</script>
```

**Model:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FinalPaginationTask.Models
{
    public class SortAndPage // used for sorting and paging
    {
        public string SortField{ get; set; }
        public string SortDirection { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int PageCount { get; set; }
        public int StartPage { get; set; }
        public int LastPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
        public Pager Pager { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Sample screenshot of what's actually happening:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

EDIT:
I'll add in my **controller** as may require additional info:

```
public ActionResult Index(UserCustom userCustomModel = null)
{
    // start load customer
    //int i;
    //if (userCustomModel != null)
    //{
    //    i = userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex;
    //}

    userCustomModel = new UserCustom
    {
        user = db.Users.ToList(),
        userDDL = db.Users.ToList()
    };
    // end load customer

    var res = (from s in userCustomModel.user
               select s);
    res = res.ToList();  /// select all users from the database

    if (userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex == 0)
    {
        userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
    }

    userCustomModel.PageSize = 10;
    userCustomModel.PageCount = ((res.Count() + userCustomModel.PageSize - 1) / userCustomModel.PageSize);
                                // (7 + 5 - 1)  = 11 / 5 = 2 pages

    if (userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex > userCustomModel.PageCount)
    {
        userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex = userCustomModel.PageCount;
    }

    userCustomModel.user = res.Skip(userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex * userCustomModel.PageSize).Take(userCustomModel.PageSize);
                                    // 0 * 5 = 0 (5) 
                                    // 1 * 5 = 5 skip 5.take 5-10


    return View(userCustomModel);
}
```

Comment: You also need to share the code which retrieves data based on the selected page number.

Comment: How is CurrentPageIndex populated and changed? And what is the initial value of CurrentPageIndex?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya how and where exactly would I get that? Where is it usually? I'm sorry for the noobish question, I'm working my way around. :)

Comment: @user65439 the initial value of CurrentPageIndex is 0. it gets iterated +1 each time the loop goes on. That's why the pages 1 and 2 is there so far.

Comment: Please share the Index action method implementation as well if you want more precise answer

Comment: @MartinZikmund thank you very much for your effortful answer, I'll look into it more. By now I can say you have helped me a lot. With regards to the " Index action method implementation", I'm not sure where is it in my code, I really don't know what it's called. But for additional info as it may help, I'll edit my post and add in my controller. I really think what you're looking for is in there.

Comment: @Kenny I have updated my answer based what I have seen in your controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the number that is displayed to the user and the index. The index values are in the range `0 .. PageCount-1`, and the displayed numbers in range `1 .. PageCount`.

Now if we look at the `Next` and `Last` links, we can see there is a mix-up of the two approaches:

```
<td class="pager"><a href="~/User/Index/@(Model.CurrentPageIndex + 1)">Next</a></td>
<td class="pager"><a href="~/User/Index/@(Model.PageCount)">Last</a></td>
```

The first link increases the `CurrentPageIndex`, which is a valid approach. However the second one sets the index to `PageCount`, while index ranges from `0 .. PageCount-1` as we established. That might explain why the `Last` link isn't working but the `Next` link should be working in this case.

Also the check:

```
@if (Model.CurrentPageIndex < Model.PageCount)
```

Will always be true, as the `CurrentPageIndex` may be at most `PageCount-1`.

I would suggest setting a breakpoint to your `Index` action method and trying individual links to see which values you are getting and if they match your expectations. While it is not directly apparent why the `Next` link does not work, it should be possible to find out from code based on the description.

> The "Next" button just returns the current page, or if I'm at another
>   page greater than 1, it goes back 1 page.

From this behavior I suspect the code-behind handling subtracts 1 from the `page` parameter, so the URL expects values in range `1 .. PageCount` but you supply values in range `0 .. PageCount-1`.

### Update

After you added the action method code to your question (each public method in the `Controller` is by convention called `action method` in ASP.NET :-) ), I am updating my code with my findings.

First your code contains the following check:

```
if (userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex == 0)
{
   userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex = 0;
}
```

You can get rid of it, because it doesn't change anything :-) .

The main problem however is here:

```
userCustomModel = new UserCustom
{
    user = db.Users.ToList(),
    userDDL = db.Users.ToList()
};
```

Here you are setting the `userCustomModel` to new instance of `UserCustom` which essentially overrides the values you recieved from the request URL. If you initialize the variable only when `null`, and query from the database directly on next line, your code should work:

```
public ActionResult Index(UserCustom userCustomModel = null)
{
    //initialize only if null
    if ( userCustomModel == null )
    {
       userCustomModel = new UserCustom();
    }
    // end load customer

    var res = db.Users.ToList(); // select all users from the database

    userCustomModel.PageSize = 10;
    userCustomModel.PageCount = ((res.Count() + userCustomModel.PageSize - 1) / userCustomModel.PageSize);
                                // (7 + 5 - 1)  = 11 / 5 = 2 pages

    if (userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex > userCustomModel.PageCount)
    {
        userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex = userCustomModel.PageCount;
    }

    userCustomModel.user = res.Skip(userCustomModel.CurrentPageIndex * userCustomModel.PageSize).Take(userCustomModel.PageSize);
              // 0 * 5 = 0 (5) 
              // 1 * 5 = 5 skip 5.take 5-10

    userCustomMode.userDDL = res;


    return View(userCustomModel);
}
```

If this does not work, please check the route, if your route parameter is in fact called `CurrentPageIndex`. Your action method parameters can be simplified to use just a single `int`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int currentPageIndex = 0)
```

Now your code could initialize the `userCustomModel` every time while using `currentPageIndex` variable as the current page.

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin! However, wait for a sec, I'm debugging my code right now and following your instructions..

Comment: After 2 days, I finally managed to get it working without EF and etc. Thank you very much for your huge help! I'll try to post my little tweak and how I got it fully working, however this is what helped me a lot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Man, I don't know why you need to handle the navigation by submitting the form.

Please remark this :

```
//$(".pager").click(function (evt) {
//    var pageindex = $(evt.target).data("pageindex");
//    $("#CurrentPageIndex").val(pageindex);
//    evt.preventDefault();
//    $("form").submit();
//});
```

and try again.

I hope it helps, because I've tried this without using your updated controller above.